# Setting include file paths for clang in .dir-locals.el

Tags: company-mode

I'm working on an embedded system and need to limit clang to only the header files of the embedded system code while I'm editing its code. I need to make the following work:

1. Make sure that company-mode with the clang backend only includes stuff inside the header files of the embedded system.
2. Make sure that C-c C-e includes system headers of the embedded platform

In other words, if a file contains `#include <stdio.h>` it should look into the folder `/home/<user>/src/include` and not e.g. `/usr/include`. I assume this should be done by making sure that `-nobuiltininc` is always passed to clang together with the appropriate `-I/home/<user>/src/include`. My question is what should I put in the `.dir-locals.el` file under `~/src`?

Comment: You need to set `company-clang-arguments`. Are you familiar with how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this seemed to do the trick

```lisp
((c-mode . ((company-clang-arguments . (list  ("-I/your/absolute/paths/here/"))))))
```

on `.dir-locals.el`